# Is it possible to run keycloak (15.0.2) in terminal without standalone.sh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have downloaded the keycloak 15.0.2 version from its official document: ‘Central Repository: org/keycloak/keycloak-dist-downloads/15.0.2’
and then I open that code on VS Code.
I print some logs in code and need to check what is the process behind it.
So, Is there any way to run that Code in VS Code Terminal or Is there any way to make a standalone.sh using any script or command? So, Changes will be reflected after I print or change anything on the code?
I know keyclock runs using standalone.sh file.
But, I am finding if any way available to run the keycloak code in the terminal to see these kinds of changes.

I print some logs in code and need to check what is the process behind it.
But i am Unable to see in standalone.sh file terminal